# Every abelian group can be embedded in a divisible group

Tags: group-theory

I've a proof of the title-statement if I can prove the following:

- every cyclic group can be embedded in $\mathbb{C}^{\star}$, the multiplicative group of complex numbers.

Can you suggest me how to prove this?

Comment: Hint: What is the element in $\mathbb C$ such that $z^n = 1$?

Comment: @John It is a $n$-th root of unity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it case by case. First the infinite cyclic groups and then the finite ones.

Comment: Thanks to John's comment, I think I have a proof for finite case, sending a generator $g$ of the group I want to embed to a $n$-th root of unity...whilst for infinite case I don't know

Comment: oh, maybe i could say: every infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to integers, and I can embed integers in the nonzero complex numbers sending $n$ to $1+\ldots +1$ $n$ times....

Comment: That is a homomorphism to the additive group not the multiplicative group. You could map $n$ to $2^n$.

Comment: @DanaeKissinger, not to *any* root of unity: to a primitive one.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes, because it must generate the cyclic group of $n$-th roots of $1$...thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Let's write $G$ as $G=F/R$ which $F$ is free abelian. It leads us to have $F=\sum\mathbb Z\leq\sum\mathbb Q$. Since $$G=F/R=\frac{\sum\mathbb Z}{R}\le\frac{\sum\mathbb Q}{R}$$ and knowing that every quotient group of a divisible group is itself a divisible group so via this way we imbedded $G$ in a divisible groups.

Comment: $\ddot\smile +\uparrow$

Comment: Notice that this proves the statement in the title of the post, but that was not the actual question: the OP wanted to know how to prove the statement in the body of the question!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Dear Mariano, yes you're right. I saw the title and wanted to post just a alternative proof for that. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Resident  What (non abelian) groups can not be embedded in a divisible group?

Comment: See, plz, the structure of a div. Group.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short proof of the whole statement (Following Hilton/Stammbach *Homological Algebra* exercise 7.2). Let $A$ be an abelian group. There is always an exact sequence $0\to K\to F \to A\to 0$ where $F$ is a free abelian group $F = \bigoplus_I\mathbb Z$. There is an embedding $\bigoplus_I\mathbb Z\hookrightarrow  \prod_I \mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \prod_I\mathbb Q$. There is a unique map $A \to (\prod_I\mathbb Q)/K$ which fits into the diagram
[image]

and the snake lemma shows that this map is a monomorphism. The group $\prod_I\mathbb Q/K$ is a quotient of a divisible group and thus divisible. Hence every abelian group can be embedded in a divisible abelian group.